# Autocomplete on @ symbol with android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to create a tagging mechanism in android where while writing out a description, when a "@" symbol is pressed, a dropdown autocomplete suggestion shows for all the users from an api call. Just wondering how I'll check the edittext if it a "@" symbol is written.

Thanks!

Comment: use `TextWatcher` and check if '@' symbol is afterTextchange then trigger autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android provides AutocompleteTextView widget.Use this widget instead of EditText and override its tokenizer.

```
 AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteId);

//Create a new Tokenizer which will get text after '@' and terminate on ' '
        autoComplete.setTokenizer(new Tokenizer() {

          @Override
          public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
            int i = text.length();

            while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
              i--;
            }

            if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
              return text;
            } else {
              if (text instanceof Spanned) {
                SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + " ");
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(), Object.class, sp, 0);
                return sp;
              } else {
                return text + " ";
              }
            }
          }

          @Override
          public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
            int i = cursor;

            while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') {
              i--;
            }

            //Check if token really started with @, else we don't have a valid token
            if (i < 1 || text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') {
              return cursor;
            }

            return i;
          }

          @Override
          public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
            int i = cursor;
            int len = text.length();

            while (i < len) {
              if (text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                return i;
              } else {
                i++;
              }
            }

            return len;
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `TextWatcher` and check if '@' symbol is afterTextchange/onTextChanged then trigger autocomplete.

further [reading here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

hope it helps :)